# Django Signal multiple Object creation

Tags: python, django

I have a signal what is send to a function `x` with a object.

```
# It easier and quicker then to do a complex update procedure. 
def x(obj):
   Element.objects.filter(id=obj.id).delete()

   if obj.is_active:
     Element.objects.create(**new_element(object))


@receiver(post_save, sender=Object)
@receiver(post_delete, sender=Object)
def update_element_receiver(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    x(instance.object)
```

If more then one user send this this signal with the same ID the function raise a `IntegrityError` in the creation step.

The error is `duplicate key value violates unique constraint "app_object_pkey" DETAIL:  Key (id)=(163497) already exists.`

I tried within a transaction but that didn't helped.

Database is PostgreSQL 9.6
Django 1.8.x

What would be the best way to prevent this error and make sure the element object exists?

Comment: First of all I am seeing syntax error at `Element.objects.filter(id=obj.id)delete()` this must be `.delete()`  Second about `object` is not able to see, And Third one is of you must use `Transactions`with `Try` `catch` and catch the error and print. You will get what exact error is occurs. And paste that here

Comment: Added error code "duplicate key value violates unique constraint already exists"

Comment: Why are you deleting and then creating? You are deleting with object id to the Element and again Creating? What exactly going on there?

Comment: It easier and quicker then to do a complex update procedure.

Comment: Which database you are using? mysql? postgresql?